Hyperlink to tcolorboxenvironment
I have defined a custom definition environment using \tcolorboxenvironment from the tcolorbox package, but I haven't been able to find out how to correctly create hyperlinks to these environments. I previously used the definition environment from amsthm and created hyperlinks using \label as in the example below, but that doesn't seem to work with \tcolorboxenvironment. Here is a minimal working example:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtheoremstyle{mydefinition}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{\color{blue}\bfseries}
{.}
{ }
{}

\theoremstyle{mydefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{enhanced jigsaw,% 
blanker,%
breakable,%
sharp corners,%
boxrule=0pt,%
opacityfill=0,%
fonttitle=\color{blue}\bfseries,%
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{blue},%
left = 12pt,
theorem style=plain,%
before skip = \baselineskip,%
after skip = \baselineskip,%
parbox=false%
}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

This hyperlink doesn't work: \hyperref[def1]{\color{blue}Definition 1}.

This hyperlink works: \hyperref[thm1]{\color{blue}Theorem 1}.

\pagebreak

\begin{definition}\label{def1}
    This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


Tcolorbox has its own tool to create new theorem environments: \newtcbtheorem
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{definition}{Definition}{
enhanced jigsaw,% 
blanker,%
breakable,%
sharp corners,%
boxrule=0pt,%
opacityfill=0,%
fonttitle=\color{blue}\bfseries,%
borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{blue},%
left = 12pt,
theorem style=plain,%
before skip = \baselineskip,%
after skip = \baselineskip,%
parbox=false%
}{def}

\begin{document}

This hyperlink doesn't work: \hyperref[def:def1]{Definition 1}.


\pagebreak

\begin{definition}{}{def1}
    This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}


Edit: There is currently a bug that breaks hyperlinks inside tcolorboxes with parbox=false. See https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/297.

You can use keytheorems to integrate tcolorbox and amsthm. The package takes care to place the link targets in the right place.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newkeytheoremstyle{mydefinition}
  {
    headfont=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    tcolorbox-no-titlebar=
      {
        enhanced jigsaw,
        blanker,%
        breakable,%
        sharp corners,%
        boxrule=0pt,%
        opacityfill=0,%
        fonttitle=\color{blue}\bfseries,%
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{blue},%
        left = 12pt,
        before skip = \baselineskip,%
        after skip = \baselineskip,%
        parbox=false%
      },
  }
\theoremstyle{mydefinition}
\newkeytheorem{definition}

%\theoremstyle{theorem} % style 'theorem' is not defined
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newkeytheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

This hyperlink works: \hyperref[def1]{\color{blue}Definition 1}.

This hyperlink works: \hyperref[thm1]{\color{blue}Theorem 1}.

\pagebreak

\begin{definition}\label{def1}
    This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}

You can also use the label theorem key to set labels if desired.
